# Getting the object out of a MemberExpression?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

So, lets say I have the following expression in C#:

```
Expression<Func<string>> expr = () => foo.Bar;
```

How do I pull out a reference to foo?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<string>> expr = () => foo.Bar;
var me = (MemberExpression)((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Expression;
var ce = (ConstantExpression)me.Expression;
var fieldInfo = ce.Value.GetType().GetField(me.Member.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var value = (Foo)fieldInfo.GetValue(ce.Value);
```

Comment: Nice, just used this to make some interaction tests more strict.

Answer (score 53):

> *I had the same problem, but somewhat more complex, and Darin Dimitrov's answer gave me a good start. I'll post my results here, despite the fact that this is an "old" question .*

---

### Case 1: The root object is an instance member

```
    this.textBox.Text    // where 'this' has type 'Form'
```

... is equivalent to the following expression tree:

```
.                                    +====================+
.                                    |  MemberExpression  |
.                                    +====================+
#                                      |                |
#                          .Expression |                | .Member
#                                      v                v
.                    +------------------+              +------------+
.                    | MemberExpression |              | MemberInfo |
.                    +------------------+              +------------+
#                      |              |                 .Name = "Text"
#          .Expression |              | .Member         .MemberType = Property
#                      v              v
.   +--------------------+          +------------+
.   | ConstantExpression |          | MemberInfo |
.   +--------------------+          +------------+
#    .Value = this                   .Name = "textBox"
#    .Type  = typeof(Form)           .MemberType = Field
```

The only place in this expression tree where you actually get an object reference is from the `ConstantExpression`: it allows you to get a reference to `this`. The basic idea to get any object reference in this tree is thus as follows:

1. Descend into the expression tree along the `.Expression` axes until you reach a `ConstantExpression` node.
2. Grab that node's `.Value` property. This is the root object reference (ie. `this` in the above example).
3. Using reflection and the `MemberInfo` nodes from the expression tree, get object references and work your way back "up" the expression tree.

Here's some code that demonstrates this:

```
Expression expr = ...;   // <-- initially set to the expression tree's root

var memberInfos = new Stack<MemberInfo>();

// "descend" toward's the root object reference:
while (expr is MemberExpression)
{
    var memberExpr = expr as MemberExpression;
    memberInfos.Push(memberExpr.Member);
    expr = memberExpr.Expression
}

// fetch the root object reference:
var constExpr = expr as ConstantExpression;
var objReference = constExpr.Value;

// "ascend" back whence we came from and resolve object references along the way:
while (memberInfos.Count > 0)  // or some other break condition
{
    var mi = memberInfos.Pop();
    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        objReference = objReference.GetType()
                                   .GetProperty(mi.Name)
                                   .GetValue(objReference, null);
    }
    else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    {
        objReference = objReference.GetType()
                                   .GetField(mi.Name)
                                   .GetValue(objReference);
    }
}
```

---

### Case 2: The root object is a static class member

```
    Form.textBox.Text    // where 'textBox' is a static member of type 'Form'
```

... results in a different expression tree. Note to the null reference at the lower left:

```
.                                    +====================+
.                                    |  MemberExpression  |
.                                    +====================+
#                                      |                |
#                          .Expression |                | .Member
#                                      v                v
.                    +------------------+              +------------+
.                    | MemberExpression |              | MemberInfo |
.                    +------------------+              +------------+
#                      |              |                 .Name = "Text"
#          .Expression |              | .Member         .MemberType = Property
#                      v              v
.                     null          +------------+
.                                   | MemberInfo |
.                                   +------------+
#                                   .Name = "textBox"
#                                   .MemberType = Field
#                                   .DeclaringType = typeof(Form)
```

Here, you cannot stop the "descend" phase by waiting for a `ConstantExpression`. Instead, you stop descending when you reach a null reference. Next, you retrieve the root object reference as follows:

```
var mi = memberInfos.Pop();
objReference = mi.DeclaringType
                 .GetField(member.Name, BindingFlags.Static)  // or .GetProperty!
                 .GetValue(null);
```

The "ascend" phase from there onwards is the same as before.

---

There are certainly more cases (such as named parameters as the root object), but I hope that by now, I've got the basic idea across, so I'll cut off here.

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation vs. just an answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler solution:

```
var pExpression = ((MemberExpression)expr.Body);
var bindingObject = Expression.Lambda(((MemberExpression)pExpression.Expression)).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Comment: Dude, you are the MVP!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, staks - your example helped me a lot! So i'd like to contribute with some addition to the first case:

To extract values from methods, one should replace code:

```
// fetch the root object reference:
var constExpr = expr as ConstantExpression;
var objReference = constExpr.Value;
```

with code:

```
    var newExpression = expr as NewExpression;
    if (newExpression != null)
    {                
        return newExpression.Constructor.Invoke(newExpression.Arguments.Select(GetObjectValue).ToArray());
    }

    var methodCallExpr = expr as MethodCallExpression;
    if (methodCallExpr != null)
    {
        var value = methodCallExpr.Method.Invoke(methodCallExpr.Object == null
                                                                 ? null
                                                                 : GetObjectValue(methodCallExpr.Object),
methodCallExpr.Arguments.Select(GetObjectValue).ToArray());
                    return value;
    }

    // fetch the root object reference:
    var constExpr = expr as ConstantExpression;
    if (constExpr == null)
    {
         return null;
    }
    var objReference = constExpr.Value;
    // ... the rest remains unchanged
```

that way one could extract values from expressions like:

```
aInstane.MethodCall(anArgument1, anArgument2) or
AType.MethodCall(anArgument1, anArgument2) or
new AType().MethodCall(anArgument1, aInstane.MethodCall(anArgument2, anArgument3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in unit tests:

```
 internal static INotifyPropertyChanged SubModel < T, TProperty > (T model, Expression < Func < T, TProperty >> pickProperty) where T: INotifyPropertyChanged {
   MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) pickProperty.Body;
   ParameterExpression parameterExpression = pickProperty.Parameters[0];
   Expression mem = memberExpression.Expression;
   var delegateType = typeof(Func < , > ).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), mem.Type);
   LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, mem, parameterExpression);
   object subModel = lambdaExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(model);
   return subModel as INotifyPropertyChanged ? ? model;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are really two separate things to do here:

1. Evaluate the result of an expression chain.
2. Evaluate the expression chain that results in the owner of the member.

Once we can do 1, then 2 becomes relatively straightforward.

Note the reason this is necessary is that in order to get the owner of the member requires getting the owner of the owner of the member (to ask it for the value of one of its members).

(Also note: the owner of the owner of the member can be a hidden closure instance, which would be the case in the example given in the question. `() => foo.Bar` is really `() => closure.foo.Bar`.)

Evaluating an expression chain can be done something like this. Note that it's recursive, since we don't know how long the chain is. (As long as there are members, you need the value of each parent to evaluate one of that parent's members.) This could also be expanded to support other kinds of expression.

```
public static object? EvaluateExpressionChain(
   this Expression me
) =>
   me switch {
      // just a value by itself
      ConstantExpression constantExp => constantExp.Value,

      // a member value of something else
      // requires recursion to evaluate unless it's a static member
      MemberExpression memberExp => memberExp.Expression is { } parentExp

         // recursively evaluate parent and then get the value of its member
         ? memberExp.Member.GetValue(EvaluateExpressionChain(parentExp))

         // a static member; can just get its value
         : memberExp.Member.GetValue(),

      // something else was in the expression that we haven't accounted for
      _ => throw new InvalidOperationException(
         $"The exp contained an unsupported subexp type {me.GetType().Name}."
      )
   };
```

Now using the above, we can just do the following to get the owner of the member:

```
public static object? GetMemberOwner(
   this LambdaExpression me
) {
   var bodyExp = me.Body;

   if (bodyExp is not MemberExpression memberExp)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Lambda did not contain a member exp.");

   if (memberExp.Expression is not { } ownerExp)
      return null; // static member

   return EvaluateExpressionChain(ownerExp);
}
```