# How to recognize a Lambda MemberExpression of type "field reference"

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have had to find a way to substitute implicit field references in a lambda expression with it's real value. For example :

```
Expression<Func<TestObject, String>> exp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    exp = t => t.SubObjs[i].TestSTR;
}
Func<TestObject, String> testFunc = exp.Compile();
String testValue = testFunc(myObj);
```

When inspecting the delegate, you can see this :

```
{t => t.SubObjs.get_Item(value(testExpression.Program+<>c__DisplayClass4).i).TestSTR}
```

When calling the delegate outside the for loop, the value of "i" is solved, by reference. But "i" have changed since it's last iteration ("i" == 1 and not 0).

So I build a specific ExpressionVisitor in order to replace the corresponding node with a ConstantExpression :

```
public class ExpressionParameterSolver : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.ToString().StartsWith("value(") && node.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var index = Expression.Lambda(node).Compile().DynamicInvoke(null);
            return Expression.Constant(index, index.GetType());
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

I don't have found a way other than .StartsWith("value(") in order to detect that the current node is a reference to a field... this kind of node inherits from FieldExpression but this class is internal, and I'm not sure FieldExpression only encapsulate what I consider an "implicit field reference".

So is there a way (an attribute or a method) to explicitly know that a MemberExpression node is an implicit field reference ???

Thanks in advance !!!

and thanks to [this stakx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613239/getting-the-object-out-of-a-memberexpression) post

Comment: Value of "i" is the only problem? Then you may simply use a local variable to make your things work easily.

Comment: I'm not the only one using this code, and unfortunately I can't force developers using my library to make local variables in their loops...

Comment: Thats right, but I think then your developers should do it right, if you allow them to override default behavior of c#, will not make them confused that even if its wrong way of coding, your library makes it right, they will be confused for code that does not use your library.

Comment: @Akash you are right. I'm trying to bypass a default c# behavior, in order to simplify the way of declaring lambda in loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fetch the [`Member`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.member.aspx) property from the expression and see whether it's a `FieldInfo`...

If you only want it to be for cases where the class is compiler-generated you could use

```
if (expression.Member is FieldInfo && 
    expression.Member
              .DeclaringType
              .IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false))
{
    ....
}
```

There can be other reasons why a type might be compiler-generated though. It doesn't sound like a terribly good idea to me.

Can't you just avoid capturing loop variables in your lambda expressions to start with?

Comment: If I write t => t.id, and if id is a field, the node.Member is also a FieldInfo. This solution is not appropriate : what I want to find, is that the node is an implicit reference to a field, and not a field itself. It's really the "value(testExpression.Program+<>c__DisplayClass4).i" Expression part that I want to detect.

Comment: @Raph: Well, as far as the expression is concerned, they're both just fields. You could check whether the field is a member of a compiler-generated class, I suppose...

Comment: No, I intend to use the lib I'm building with exactly this kind of lambda... And you are really right : the problem is to make the difference between implicit and explicit compiler-generated parameters... <Scratching brain/>...

Comment: @Raph: Given that the lambda expression really does represent capturing the iteration variable, I would just state it as a natural side-effect. It would be much better not to get into this situation than to try to work around it, IMO.

Comment: I use theses lambdas to extract explicit delegates to any object properties and I need to map sub properties (as in a list 4 ex), in order to map them to the getter and setter of a dynamically build type. I know it is a pretty strange approach, but I don't have choice. I have to handle properties inside indexed ones...