# Getting root of expression

Tags: c#, .net

Let me show you some code right away:

```
class MyClass {

    public MyClass(Customer c) {
        ExtractRoot(() => c.FirstName);
    }
}
```

`ExtractRoot` is accepting a `Expression<Func<object>>` as its parameter.

I am trying to extract the customer object 'c' from the expression tree. I am passing it to the `ExtractRoot` method, and I know how to get the `ConstantExpression` which represents the customer object. But, when I call `ToString()` on that object I get this printed:
MyAssemblyName.CustomNamespace.MyClass+<>c__DisplayClass2

Can someone please explain what this means and why I am not getting my customer's `ToString()` method called, it is as if the object I am getting is not the customer, why and what am I getting back?

Finally, how can I get the actual customer object, or the root of my expression?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, do you mean `constantExpression.Value`?

Comment: () => c.FirstName is a typeless delegate. To get to the root you need a delegate in the form of c => c.FirstName, i think

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson correct, i keep descending the tree until i arrive at the `ConstantExpression` then i get its value like you said but i get what i showed you ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "DisplayClass" name mean when calling lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401860/what-does-displayclass-name-mean-when-calling-lambda)

Comment: Why the down vote !! and this isn't a complete duplicate @ErikSchierboom because the related answer covers part of my question but what about getting the actual root object.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer it turned out that you can but you need some reflection, i found the answer in another stackoverflow question and put the link in my answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the complete solution to my answer which has two parts:

1. Why the DisplayClass and what it means can be found in the answer to this question: [What does “DisplayClass” name mean when calling lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401860/what-does-displayclass-name-mean-when-calling-lambda)
2. How to get the actual root of the expression *(which is possible by the way)* can be found in this questions answer: [Getting the object out of a MemberExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613239/getting-the-object-out-of-a-memberexpression).