# Get Name and Value of a property of a POCO object using an expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, poco

I'm looking for a way to get the name and value of a proptery in a POCO object. I've tried many solutions but can't seem to get them to work. I really liked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613239/getting-the-object-out-of-a-memberexpression) older solution but it causes a null ref error.

Here's kind of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class POCO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public class POCOValidationResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Validator<T> where T : class
{
    public T Entity { get; set; }

    public abstract POCOValidationResult Validate();

    protected POCOValidationResult ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, int maxLength)
    {
        var propertyName = getPropertyName(expression);
        var propertyValue = getPropertyValue(expression);

        if (propertyValue.Length > maxLength)
        {
            return new POCOValidationResult()
            {
                Error = string.Format("{0} value is too long. Must be less or equal to {1}", propertyName, maxLength.ToString())
            };
        }

        return new POCOValidationResult() { IsValid = true };
    }

    internal string getPropertyName(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpersion = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;

        return memberExpersion.Member.Name;
    }
    internal string getPropertyValue<R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expression)
    {
        //struggling to get this to work

        var me = (MemberExpression)expression.Body; // (MemberExpression)((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Expression;
        var ce = (ConstantExpression)me.Expression; // Error here!
        var fieldInfo = ce.Value.GetType().GetField(me.Member.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(ce.Value);
    }
}

public class POCOValidator : Validator<POCO>
{
    public override POCOValidationResult Validate()
    {
        var surnameValidationResult = ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(p => p.Surname, 10);

        if (!surnameValidationResult.IsValid)
            return surnameValidationResult;

        //var descriptionValidationResult = ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(p => p.Description, 100);

        //if (!descriptionValidationResult.IsValid)
        //    return descriptionValidationResult;

        //var nameValidationResult = ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(p => p.Name, 15);

        //if (!nameValidationResult.IsValid)
        //    return nameValidationResult;

        return new POCOValidationResult() { IsValid = true };
    }
}

public class WorkerBee
{
    public void ImDoingWorkReally()
    {
        var pocoVallidation = new POCOValidator()
        {
            Entity = new POCO()
            { 
                ID = 1, 
                Name = "James", 
                Surname = "Dean", 
                Description = "I'm not 007!"
            }
        };

        var vallidationResult = pocoVallidation.Validate();

        if (!vallidationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        //continue to do work...
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workerBee = new WorkerBee();

        workerBee.ImDoingWorkReally();
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to get the Property's name and value [by using an Expression `(p => p.Surname)` as a parameter in the method `ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(...)`]. The problem is that I'm getting a null ref error in `getPropertyValue(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)` when it calls `var ce = (ConstantExpression)me.Expression;`

So does anyone have ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I really appreciate it and hope that my question also is helpful for others as I think this can be rather useful if I can get this to work.

**EDIT**: I've made the change as mentioned below in the comments and still getting the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression" when I run my unit test.

Comment: I am pretty sure this will explain the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567857/why-are-some-object-properties-unaryexpression-and-others-memberexpression/3573250#3573250 Please delete your question if that is the case.

Comment: This does look like a duplicate to me. Per leppie's advice, you should change the method declaration to `string getPropertyValue<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)` so that the correct expression type is passed (i.e. one with a body). I would spend the 5 minutes to test it myself, but you didn't bother to include [a minimal, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I appreciate the help but changing the declaration did not help as I'm still getting the same error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'."

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution (unfortunately the comments were not helpful). Here's the code that works:

```
public class POCO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class POCOValidationResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Validator<T> where T : class
{
    public T Entity { get; set; }

    public abstract POCOValidationResult Validate();

    protected POCOValidationResult ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, int maxLength)
    {
        var propertyName = getPropertyName(expression);
        var propertyValue = getPropertyValue(expression);

        if (propertyValue.Length > maxLength)
        {
            return new POCOValidationResult()
            {
                Error = string.Format("{0} value is too long. Must be less or equal to {1}", propertyName, maxLength.ToString())
            };
        }

        return new POCOValidationResult() { IsValid = true };
    }

    internal string getPropertyName(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpersion = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;

        return memberExpersion.Member.Name;
    }
    internal string getPropertyValue(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        return propertyInfo.GetValue(Entity, null).ToString();
    }
}

public class POCOValidator : Validator<POCO>
{
    public override POCOValidationResult Validate()
    {
        var surnameValidationResult = ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(p => p.Surname, 10);

        if (!surnameValidationResult.IsValid)
            return surnameValidationResult;

        var descriptionValidationResult = ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(p => p.Description, 100);

        if (!descriptionValidationResult.IsValid)
            return descriptionValidationResult;

        var nameValidationResult = ValidateStringPropertyToLengthOf(p => p.Name, 15);

        if (!nameValidationResult.IsValid)
            return nameValidationResult;

        return new POCOValidationResult() { IsValid = true };
    }
}

public class WorkerBee
{
    public void ImDoingWorkReally()
    {
        var pocoVallidation = new POCOValidator()
        {
            Entity = new POCO()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "James",
                Surname = "Dean",
                Description = "I'm not 007!"
            }
        };

        var vallidationResult = pocoVallidation.Validate();

        if (!vallidationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        //continue to do work...
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workerBee = new WorkerBee();

        workerBee.ImDoingWorkReally();
    }
}
```

Note the change for `getPropertyValue`:

```
    internal string getPropertyValue(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        return propertyInfo.GetValue(Entity, null).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that MaudDib's *getPropertyValue* method only works for properties directly on the object.  e.g. it will work for myObj.Value, but not for myObj.Something.Value.  The following works for both.  (I don't know if there's a better way, though).

Usage: `var myValue = GetPropertyValue(myObj, o => o.Something.Value);`

```
public static object GetPropertyValue<T>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    var members = new CompositeExpressionVisitor().GetMembers(expression);
    object currentVal = obj;
    foreach (var part in members)
    {
        currentVal = GetPropertyValue(currentVal, part);
    }

    return currentVal;
}

private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, MemberInfo member)
{
    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)member;
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
}

private class CompositeExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly List<MemberInfo> _members = new List<MemberInfo>();

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        _members.Add(node.Member);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<MemberInfo> GetMembers(Expression e)
    {
        Visit(e is LambdaExpression expression ? expression.Body : e);
        _members.Reverse();
        return _members;
    }
}
```

And, if you want the full path of the expression, e.g. you don't just want the leaf... you can do this:

Usage: `var myValue = NameOf(() => myObj.Something.Value);`

Returns: `myObj.Something.Value`

Or: `var myValue = NameOf(() => myObj.Something.Value, 1);`

Returns: `Something.Value`

```
public static string NameOf(Expression<Func<object>> expression, int startIndex = 0)
{
    return new CompositeExpressionVisitor().GetPath(expression, startIndex);
}

private class CompositeExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly List<string> _parts = new List<string>();

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        _parts.Add(node.Member.Name);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        _parts.Add(node.Name);
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

    public string GetPath(Expression e, int startIndex = 0)
    {
        Visit(e is LambdaExpression expression ? expression.Body : e);
        _parts.Reverse();
        return string.Join(".", _parts.Skip(startIndex));
    }
}
```