# Get name and value of static class properties using Expression Trees

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I have a generic method which compares 2 properties, if value are different it logs the changes and Saves.

```
    private void SaveIfChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression, T newValue)
            {

                var expr = (MemberExpression)expression.Body; 
                var obj = (MemberExpression)expr.Expression; 
                var fieldsOfObj = (ConstantExpression)obj.Expression;
                var valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj = ((FieldInfo)obj.Member).GetValue(fieldsOfObj.Value); 

                var propertyInfo = ((PropertyInfo)expr.Member); 
                var oldPropertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj, null); 

                if (oldPropertyValue.Equals(newValue)) return;       


 var desctiptionAttributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                Log("{0} changed from {1} to {2}",desctiptionAttributes[0].Description, oldPropertyValue, newValue);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj, newValue, null);

                Save();
            }
```

It works fine when I pass Properties which are members of a non-static class, but when I pass a static property then it doesn't work.

```
SaveIfChanged(() => _settings.DomainName, DomainName); // Works
SaveIfChanged(() => Settings.DomainName, DomainName);  //Doesn't work
```

I also know how to get fields/properties of static class, but only when I have the class name. I just don't know how can I combine the following with my method.

```
        Type s= typeof(Settings);
        FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(null).ToString());
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you try to access property `Expression` in `var fieldsOfObj = (ConstantExpression)obj.Expression;`.

`MemberExpression` is mainly composed of two properties:

- `Expression` gets the containing object of the field or property.
- `Member` gets the field or property to be accessed.

In the first case (`_settings.DomainName`) the property `Expression` gets a `memberExpression` object containing `_settings`, and property `Member` returns a `MemberInfo` pointing to DomainName.

In the second case (`Settings.DomainName`), the property `Expression` returns null because you are not accessing the property of an instance, you are accessing a static property. In the code the object `obj` is null, and that's when the problem comes.

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954131/5178207) for details.

To solve this issue, you can do this:

```
private static void SaveIfChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression, T newValue)
{
    var expr = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;

    object valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj = null;
    if (expr.Expression != null)
    {
        var obj = (MemberExpression)expr.Expression;
        var fieldsOfObj = (ConstantExpression)obj.Expression;
        valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj = ((FieldInfo)obj.Member).GetValue(fieldsOfObj.Value);
    }

    var propertyInfo = ((PropertyInfo)expr.Member);
    var oldPropertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj, null);

    if (oldPropertyValue.Equals(newValue)) return;

    var desctiptionAttributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    Log("{0} changed from {1} to {2}", desctiptionAttributes[0].Description, oldPropertyValue, newValue);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(valuesOfAllFieldsOfObj, newValue, null);

    Save();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was confused about.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing `Expression<Func<T>> expression` will allow your method to be called with anything. To be really flexible, why not compile and call the method? then you dont need any of this magic...

```
if (expression.Compile()() != newValue)
{
    ....
}
```